# Dax time intelligents function for semester equivalent to DATESYTD()

Tags: powerbi, dax

Need to calculate The Semester to date just like the functions

```
 1. DATESMTD()
 2. DATESQTD()
 3. DATESYTD()
```

This function does not exist. How can I create a dax measure that does this for a semester?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Semester_to_date = 
VAR MaxDate = VAR MaxDate = MAX('Calendar Lookup'[Date])    -- Variable to get the max date
VAR MinDate =                                               -- Variable to get the min date for the semester
IF(
    MONTH(MAX('Calendar Lookup'[Date]))<=6,                 -- if month <= then 6
    DATE(YEAR(MAX('Calendar Lookup'[Date])),1,1),           -- then max date = first day of january (month 1)
    DATE(YEAR(MAX('Calendar Lookup'[Date])),7,1)            -- else max date = first day of july (month 7)
)

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Your Measure] or expression,                           -- Measure or expression you would like to analyse
    DATESBETWEEN('Calendar Lookup'[Date],MinDate,MaxDate)   -- Check between variables MinDate and MaxDate
)
```